# Web scraping using Beautiful Soup: not displaying the entire table?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm working on a project right now that requires scraping some data using Beautiful Soup. I'm trying to scrape the New York Times COVID data for counties in Pennsylvania. The following code I ran works, but it's only returning 10 of the 67 counties needed.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

httpString ='https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2021/us/pennsylvania-covid-cases.html'
print(httpString)

page = requests.get(httpString)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
covidtable = soup.find(class_ = "g-table super-table withchildren")
print(covidtable)
table = pd.read_html(str(covidtable))
print(table)
```

Comment: In 9 out of ten cases, partial results with BeautifulSoup result from parsing the html without JavaScript running (which modifies the document object model and can add additional data later). Have you tried using `selenium` with an appropriate web drivers, so you can load the page and have the JavaScript execute?

Comment: Have you actually looked at the page?  It only displays 10 counties unless you click the "Show All" button.

Comment: @TimRoberts is correct, and if you click the button with the browser's developers tools open on the network tab, you'll see that it doesn't actually load the data when you click that button, it just reveals it (and loads a number of svgs) - so you definitely need some sort of JavaScript capable browser. `selenium` will allow you to "click the button" from code and allow the table to load completely.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a browser at all. Just request the data in json format.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('https://static01.nyt.com/newsgraphics/2021/coronavirus-tracking/data/pages/us/pennsylvania-covid-cases/data.json').json()
df = pd.DataFrame(r['clusters'])
print(df)
```